# Crystal Reports set record number in formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Would anyone know of a way to manually specify a record number within a formula, in Crystal Reports?

For instance, I have a report linked to an SQL server View that sits on top of a table that contains 20 records. This view selects the fields I need and then orders by the highest value to the lowest.

The report then pulls these records into the report in that order. What I would like to do is to be able to write a formula that can select a record based on its number.

I know I can reference **RecordNumber** in a formula (i.e. If RecordNumber = 5 Then...) but this only works in the Detail section once it actually shows record number 5, and if I place a formula in the header section it just displays **False** as the header only shows the first record.

I need to create a formula that sets the record number and then displays the desired value of that record number in the header (i.e. something like:

*Set RecordNumber = 5*

*ToText ({table.value})*

Can anyone help or is Crystal just not that sophisticated?

Comment: if not details where are you displaying the data in crystal reports?

Comment: I'm displaying it in the header section. I wonder if there is a way of specifying 'on change of' in an actual formula, much like the selection that can be made in a graph.